# Hyperlink text in cells

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

How to do you set up hyperlink text in cells from existing tables? My `<td>` element has a child `<a>` that is the text to display in the table and has a href attribute for the link but in the tabulator table cell get the innerHTML of the `<td>` and shows the outerHTML of the `<a>`. Any help is appreciated!

I loaded the tabulator to look at the existing table. my table has the id of "table" and the js I used to do this is from the examples
`var table = new Tabulator("#table", {});`
once it loads the cells that had a hyperlink text `<a>` element show the outerHTML.

Edit: here is a sample of what i am having problems with.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>column 1</th>
          <th>column 2</th>
          <th>column 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77340782/hyperlink-text-in-cells">Displayed cell text 1</a>
          </td>
          <td>cell text 2</td>
          <td>cell text 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
      //define some sample data
 var table = new Tabulator("#table", {});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the code for the html table and your tabulator setup? A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: @Timur i edited the original to have a code snippet showing what i am referring to and to the one that helped edit the original question and fixed my tags thank you! your name disappeared when i edited it.

Comment: Hi Troy, that helps a lot.  Please see my answer below.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rowFormatter` callback of Tabulator to iterate each row and change the way the row's cell element is displayed.  Below example finds the first cell of each row in the table and makes the innerHTML of the cell to be the link.

```js
let table = new Tabulator("#table", {
  rowFormatter: (row) => {
    let col_1 = row.getCells()[0]

    col_1.getElement().innerHTML = col_1.getValue()
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>column 1</th>
        <th>column 2</th>
        <th>column 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77340782/hyperlink-text-in-cells">Displayed cell text 1</a>
        </td>
        <td>cell text 2</td>
        <td>cell text 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks! I'll see if I can get that function to work with my existing tables! Either way you have me on the right path!

Comment: How would you set it up to check to see if any of the cells have a link and format it if not then leave it alone. I know the js you have has it only looking at the first column

Comment: I figured it out finally! Thank you so much for your help! I'll post a code snippet once I can!